# How can I do real-time voice activity detection in Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech, pyaudio

I am performing a voice activity detection on the recorded audio file to detect speech vs non-speech portions in the waveform.

The output of the classifier looks like (highlighted green regions indicate speech):

[image]

The only issue I face here is making it work for a stream of audio input (for eg: from a microphone) and do real-time analysis for a stipulated time-frame.

I know `PyAudio` can be used to record speech from the microphone dynamically and there a couple of real-time visualization examples of a waveform, spectrum, spectrogram, etc, but could not find anything relevant to carrying out feature extraction in a near real-time manner.

Comment: pyaudio's latest release is 3 years old right now

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should try using Python bindings to [webRTC VAD from Google](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad). It's  lightweight, fast and provides very reasonable results, based on GMM modelling. As the decision is provided per frame, the latency is minimal.

```
# Run the VAD on 10 ms of silence. The result should be False.
import webrtcvad
vad = webrtcvad.Vad(2)

sample_rate = 16000
frame_duration = 10  # ms
frame = b'\x00\x00' * int(sample_rate * frame_duration / 1000)
print('Contains speech: %s' % (vad.is_speech(frame, sample_rate))
```

Also, [this](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/asr/vad/) article might be useful for you.

**UPDATE December 2022**

As the topic still draws attention, I'd like to update my answer. [SileroVAD](https://github.com/snakers4/silero-vad) is very fast and very accurate VAD that was released recently under MIT license.

Comment: Nice find! I completely overlooked WebRTC module. Although, I've got a feasible solution using Auditok, I'll accept yours as it is close to what I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you for `Auditok`. Wasn't aware of it's existance

Comment: Thanks for linking to [the Google paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=14816012096757342164&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en). It's terribly old now in Deep Learning terms, but it's already RNN based and it is easy to get a grip on the available techniques knowing this is called "Voice Activity Detection" (VAD when abbreviated) and/or following up from that paper to newer ones maybe.

Comment: [My first attempt](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/issues/29#issuecomment-626590955)  at the py-webrtcvad route, using sounddevice as the audio input source. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463146/python-webrtc-voice-activity-detection-is-wrong

Answer (score 5):

I found out that [LibROSA](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/index.html) could be one of the solutions to your problem. There's a simple tutorial on [Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/sound-event-classification-using-machine-learning-8768092beafc) on using Microphone streaming to realise real-time prediction.

Let's use Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT) as the feature extractor, the author explains:

> To calculate STFT, Fast Fourier transform window size(n_fft) is used
> as 512. According to the equation n_stft = n_fft/2 + 1, 257 frequency
> bins(n_stft) are calculated over a window size of 512. The window is
> moved by a hop length of 256 to have a better overlapping of the
> windows in calculating the STFT.
>
> `stft = np.abs(librosa.stft(trimmed, n_fft=512, hop_length=256, win_length=512))`

```
# Plot audio with zoomed in y axis
def plotAudio(output):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1, figsize=(20,10))
    plt.plot(output, color='blue')
    ax.set_xlim((0, len(output)))
    ax.margins(2, -0.1)
    plt.show()

# Plot audio
def plotAudio2(output):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1, figsize=(20,4))
    plt.plot(output, color='blue')
    ax.set_xlim((0, len(output)))
    plt.show()

def minMaxNormalize(arr):
    mn = np.min(arr)
    mx = np.max(arr)
    return (arr-mn)/(mx-mn)

def predictSound(X):
    clip, index = librosa.effects.trim(X, top_db=20, frame_length=512, hop_length=64) # Empherically select top_db for every sample
    stfts = np.abs(librosa.stft(clip, n_fft=512, hop_length=256, win_length=512))
    stfts = np.mean(stfts,axis=1)
    stfts = minMaxNormalize(stfts)
    result = model.predict(np.array([stfts]))
    predictions = [np.argmax(y) for y in result]
    print(lb.inverse_transform([predictions[0]])[0])
    plotAudio2(clip)

CHUNKSIZE = 22050 # fixed chunk size
RATE = 22050

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, 
rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNKSIZE)

#preprocessing the noise around
#noise window
data = stream.read(10000)
noise_sample = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float32)
print("Noise Sample")
plotAudio2(noise_sample)
loud_threshold = np.mean(np.abs(noise_sample)) * 10
print("Loud threshold", loud_threshold)
audio_buffer = []
near = 0

while(True):
    # Read chunk and load it into numpy array.
    data = stream.read(CHUNKSIZE)
    current_window = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float32)
    
    #Reduce noise real-time
    current_window = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=current_window, noise_clip=noise_sample, verbose=False)
    
    if(audio_buffer==[]):
        audio_buffer = current_window
    else:
        if(np.mean(np.abs(current_window))<loud_threshold):
            print("Inside silence reign")
            if(near<10):
                audio_buffer = np.concatenate((audio_buffer,current_window))
                near += 1
            else:
                predictSound(np.array(audio_buffer))
                audio_buffer = []
                near
        else:
            print("Inside loud reign")
            near = 0
            audio_buffer = np.concatenate((audio_buffer,current_window))

# close stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Code credit to: **Chathuranga Siriwardhana**

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/chathuranga95/SoundEventClassification/blob/master/continuous_sound_classification%20-%20from%20mic.ipynb).

Answer (score 3):

Audio usually has a low bitrate, so I don't see any problem of writing your code completely in [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) and `python`. And if you need low-level array access consider [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/). Also profile your code e.g. with [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler). ALso note there is [`scipy.signal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/signal.html) for more advanced signal processing.

Usually audio processing works in samples. So you define a sample size for your process, and then run a method to decide if that sample contains speech or not.

```py
import numpy as np

def main_loop():
    stream = <create stream with your audio library>
    while True:
        sample = stream.readframes(<define number of samples / time to read>)
        print(is_speech(sample))

def is_speech(sample):
    audio = np.array(sample)

    < do you processing >

    # e.g. simple loudness test
    return np.any(audio > 0.8):
```

That should get you pretty far.

Comment: I especially liked the < do your processing > bit of this answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two approaches here,

1. Threshold Approach
2. Small, deployable, Neural net. Approach

The first one is fast, **feasible** and can be implemented and **tested very fast**. while the second one is a bit more difficult to implement. I think you are a bit familiar with 2nd option already.

in the case of the 2nd approach, you will be needing a dataset of speeches that are labeled in a sequence of **binary classification** like `00000000111111110000000011110000`. The neural net should be small and optimized for running on edge devices like mobile.

You can check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md) out from TensorFlow

[This](https://github.com/jtkim-kaist/VAD) is a voice activity detector. I think it's for your purpose.

Also, check these out.

https://github.com/eesungkim/Voice_Activity_Detector

https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio

of course, you should **compare performance** of the mentioned toolkits and models and the **feasibility** of the **implementation** of mobile devices.

Answer (score -1):

I recently found this question while looking for an answer to the same question, thanks for all the suggestions. I found 3 more detectors. picovoice is by far better then webrtc. speechbrain and nvidia don't support real-time which kinda sucks

-picovoice cobra: https://picovoice.ai/docs/cobra/
-speechbrain: https://speechbrain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/speechbrain.pretrained.interfaces.html#speechbrain.pretrained.interfaces.VAD
-nvidia: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/nemo/user-guide/docs/en/stable/asr/speech_classification/models.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33963110)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).